Issue with bind-Value, object failing to be created
I'm working on a Blazor application and I'm having trouble with my login form. The LoginModel object is always empty when it's passed to my HandleLogin method, causing the login process to fail. Additionally, I'm encountering the following error:
Severity    Code    Description    Project    File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)    RZ9991    The attribute names could not be inferred from bind attribute 'bind-Value'. Bind attributes should be of the form 'bind' or 'bind-value' along with their corresponding optional parameters like 'bind-value:event', 'bind:format' etc.

Here is the relevant part of my code:
`
@page "/login"
@layout BTDMiddleware___Frontend.Components.Layout.LoginLayout
@inject BTDMiddleware___Frontend.Components.AuthService AuthService
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@inject HttpClient HttpClient
@using BTDMiddleware___Frontend.Components.Modals
@using BTDMiddleware___Frontend.Components.Model

<style>
    /* Styling code omitted for brevity */
</style>

<div class="login-container">
    <div class="login-left">
        <h1>Welcome Page</h1>
        <p>Sign in to continue access</p>
        <p>Server URI: @serverUri</p>
        <p>HttpClient Base Address: @httpClientBaseAddress</p>
    </div>
    <div class="login-right">
        <div class="login-card">
            <h3>Sign In</h3>
            <div class="social-login">
                <a href="#">Sign In with Azure</a>
            </div>
            <div class="separator">
                <div class="separator-line"></div>
                <div class="separator-text">OR</div>
                <div class="separator-line"></div>
            </div>
            <EditForm Model="@loginModel" OnValidSubmit="@HandleLogin" FormName="loginForm">
                <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                <ValidationSummary />
                <div>
                    <label>Username:</label>
                    <InputText @bind-Value="loginModel.Username" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Password:</label>
                    <InputText @bind-Value="loginModel.Password" type="password" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Continue</button>
            </EditForm>
            <div class="sign-up">
                Or Sign Up Using
                <a href="/signup">SIGN UP</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<ErrorModal Show="@showErrorModal" ShowChanged="@OnShowChanged" ErrorMessage="@errorMessage" />

@code {
    private LoginModel loginModel = new LoginModel();
    private bool showErrorModal = false;
    private string errorMessage = string.Empty;
    private string serverUri;
    private string httpClientBaseAddress;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        serverUri = Navigation.BaseUri;
        httpClientBaseAddress = HttpClient.BaseAddress?.ToString() ?? "No base address set";
        Console.WriteLine($"Server URI: {serverUri}");
        Console.WriteLine($"HttpClient Base Address: {httpClientBaseAddress}");
    }

    private async Task HandleLogin()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HandleLogin method called");
        Console.WriteLine($"Attempting login with Username: {loginModel.Username}, Password: {loginModel.Password}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Server URI: {serverUri}");
        Console.WriteLine($"HttpClient Base Address: {httpClientBaseAddress}");

        try
        {
            var response = await AuthService.Login(loginModel);
            Console.WriteLine($"Login request sent. Status Code: {response.StatusCode}");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                if (await AuthService.IsAuthenticated())
                {
                    Navigation.NavigateTo("/");
                }
                else
                {
                    errorMessage = "Invalid username or password.";
                    showErrorModal = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine($"Login request failed. Status Code: {response.StatusCode}, Reason: {content}");
                errorMessage = "An error occurred during login. Please try again.";
                showErrorModal = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception occurred during login: {ex.Message}");
            errorMessage = "An error occurred during login. Please try again.";
            showErrorModal = true;
        }
    }

    private async Task OnShowChanged(bool value)
    {
        showErrorModal = value;
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
`

In my HandleLogin method, loginModel.Username and loginModel.Password are always null or empty, even though I have bound them correctly in the form using @bind-Value.
What could be causing the LoginModel object to be empty when the form is submitted, and how can I fix this issue? Additionally, how can I resolve the RZ9991 error regarding the @bind-Value attribute?
Additional Information:

I'm using Blazor Server.
The login form is displayed correctly and does not show any validation errors.
The HandleLogin method is triggered as expected when the form is submitted.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I modified the Blazor login page to handle form input values using local variables instead of directly binding the loginModel. The goal was to avoid binding issues by manually creating the loginModel object during form submission.
**What I Tried:
**

Removed the binding of loginModel to the input fields.
Introduced local variables username and password to hold the input values.
Updated the HandleLogin method to create and populate the loginModel object with these local variables during form submission.

**Expected Outcome:
**I expected the form to accept user inputs for the username and password, store these values in the local variables, and then use these values to create a loginModel object during form submission. This object would be used to send a login request to the server.
**Actual Result:
**The form successfully accepted and stored the input values in the local variables. During form submission, the loginModel was correctly created and populated with these values, and the login request was sent as expected without any binding issues.

Is this a SSR or Interactive page?  I'm guessing Interactive.  Can you show LoginModel?

If I read this correctly you have two issues:

var response = await AuthService.Login(loginModel); is submitting an empty model.
You have a RZ9991 error about binding.

Tell me if I'm wrong, but I think we can build a Minimal Reproducible Example from your code that looks like this to test the form.
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<EditForm Model="@loginModel" OnValidSubmit="@HandleLogin" FormName="loginForm">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <div>
        <label>Username:</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="loginModel.Username" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="loginModel.Password" type="password" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="m-2 text-end">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Continue</button>
    </div>
</EditForm>

<h3>Edit Form Data</h3>
<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>Username: @loginModel.Username</pre>
    <pre>Password: @loginModel.Password</pre>
</div>

<h3>Submitted Data</h3>
<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>Username: @_submittedModel.Username</pre>
    <pre>Password: @_submittedModel.Password</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private LoginModel loginModel = new();
    private LoginModel _submittedModel = new();

    private async Task HandleLogin()
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        _submittedModel = loginModel;
    }

    public class LoginModel
    {
        public string? Username { get; set; }
        public string? Password { get; set; }
    }
}

It works, so I'm either missing something in your code or you aren't sharing everything with us.

I'm not a Blazor user, but isn't it case-sensitive? So it should be bind-value="..." not bind-Value="...", right?

@Dia - Yes it's case sensitive, but not in the way you mean.   @bind-Value is razor syntax to tell the Razor compiler to build the C# class with binding to the parameters Value and ValueChanged.   The Input controls use the naming convention Value, ValueChanged and ValueExpression for their primary parameters.   @bind-Dai means bind to Dia and DiaChanged and DiaExpression.

You're correct, I'm not sure why it's not working for me. Let me give some more context, it's a Blazor Web Assembly App, in general throughout this project I am unable to bind values to a object. Is there something I'm missing?

All I can say is create a [MRE] that produces your problem.  Without a view of your project, or a demo project that exhibits the problem,  I'm not sure anyone can answer why.  Where is interactivity set [Global or Per Page/Component]?
